# avoid sending mail in newsletter success when customer create new account

Tags: magento-1.9, email, newsletter

how to avoid sending mail in newsletter when customer created new account.
when we register on site at that time we get 2 mails , first is welcome mail and another is newsletter subscribe. we need to stop sending this second mail .

Comment: Which magento version ...are you using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to
`\app\locale\en_US\template\email\newsletter_subscr_success.html`
delete full page content . and from now you don't get any mail on news later subscription.

Comment: Tricky, or hacky? Just what happens when this blank file is loaded by Magento?

Comment: nothing problem , i just try this in my site . all is ok . you want url to see this?